# Prove $f(z)+f(z^2)+\cdots+f(z^n)$ is harmonic in $|z|\lt1$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove $f(z)+f(z^2)+\cdots+f(z^n)$ is harmonic in $|z|\lt1$ which $f(z)$ is harmonic in $|z|\lt1$ and $f(0)=0$.

Comment: What is the definition of harmonic? $\partial \bar{\partial}=0$?

Comment: equivalent to analytic

Comment: $f$ is a real valued? or complex valued?

Comment: complex valued.

Answer (score 0):

We may assume that $f$ is real valued. There is an analytic function $F$ with real part $f$ and $f(z)+f(z^{2})+...+f(z^{n})$ is the real part of the analytic function $F(z)+F(z^{2})+...+F(z^{n})$.